# How can I create an array of 'n' positive integers where none of the subsequences of the array have equal sum?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization

I was watching a lecture on the question "subsequence sum equals to k" in which you're given an array of n positive integers and a target sum = k. Your task is to check if any of the subsequence of the array have a sum equal to the target sum. The recursive solution works in O(2^N). The lecturer said that if we memoize the recursive solution, the time complexity will drop to O(N*K). But as much as I understand, memoization simply removes overlapping subproblems. So if all of the subsequences have different sum, won't the time complexity of the solution still be O(2^N)? Just to test this hypothesis, I was trying to create an array of n positive integers where none of the subsequences have equal sum.

Also, I tried the tabulation method and was unable to understand why the time complexity drops in the case of tabulation. Please point to any resource where I can learn exactly what subproblems does tabulation avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that O(NK) is not always smaller than O(2<sup>N</sup>).  If K = 2<sup>N</sup> for example, then O(KN) = O(N * 2<sup>N</sup>), which is larger.

Furthermore, this is the sort of range you're dealing with when every subsequence sum is different.

If your N integers are powers of 2, for example: [2<sup>0</sup>, 2<sup>1</sup>, 2<sup>2</sup>, ...], then every subsequence has a different sum, and K=2<sup>N</sup> is the *smallest* positive integer that isn't a subsequence sum.

The tabulation method is only an improvement when K is known to be relatively small.

Answer (score 1):

If each value in the array is a different, positive power of the same base, no two sums will be equal.

Python code:

```py
def f(A):
  sums = set([0])
  for a in A:
    new_sums = set()
    for s in sums:
      new_sum = s + a
      if new_sum in sums:
        print(new_sum)
        return None
      new_sums.add(new_sum)
    sums = sums.union(new_sums)
  return sums

for b in range(2, 10):
  A = []
  for p in range(5):
    A.append(b**p)
  sums = f(A)
  print(A)
  print(len(sums))
  print(sums)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the recursive case without memoization, you'll compute the sums for all subsequences, which has `O(2^N)` complexity.

Now consider the memoization case.
Let `dp[i][j] = 1` if there exists a subsequence in the array `arr[i:]` that has sum `j`, else `dp[i][j] = 0`.

The algorithm is

```
for each index i in range(n,0,-1):
    j = array[i]
    for each x in range(0,k):
        dp[i][x] += dp[i+1][x]
        if dp[i+1][x] == 1:
            dp[i][x+j] = 1
return dp[0][k]
```

For each index, we traverse the subsequence sums seen till yet (in range `k`), and mark them True for the current index. For each such sum, we also add the value of the current element, and mark that True.

**Which sub-problems were reduced?**

We just track if sum `x` is possible in a subarray. In the recursive case, there could be 100 subsequences that have sum `x`. Here, since we're using a bool to track if `x` is possible in the subarray, we effectively avoid going over all subsequences just to check if the sum is possible.

For each index, since we do a `O(k)` traversal of going through all sums, the complexity becomes `O(N*k)`.

Comment: The solution that you posted, I understand it to be 'tabulation' method instead of 'memoization' method. Correct me if I am wrong. Can you confirm if I write the recursive code and simply store all the answers that each call returns, and return the answer if it's already stored, will it improve the worst case time complexity? I am unable to write the code here as it's only a comment but let me know if you don't get what I am talking about.

Comment: I meant a recursive function of form R(index, target, arr, n, dp) which takes dp[index][target](initialised with -1) as input and for every index-target pair checks if dp[index][target] equal -1. If it is -1, the return value calculated for the given index-target pair is stored and returned. If it is not -1, the stored value is returned, thus avoiding re-calculation. So does this method improve the worst case time complexity? Like if none of the subsequences have equal sum, won't the time complexity be same as recursive function?